# A property of the Baire $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

This problem was assigned in a real analysis class I'm in and I have not been able to solve it.

Let $X$ be a topological space. For each $x\in X$ let $\varphi_x\colon C(X,[0,1]) \to [0,1]$ be given by $\varphi_x(f)=f(x)$ for each $f\in C(X,[0,1])$. Let $\varphi\colon X\to [0,1]^{C(X,[0,1])}$ be given by $\varphi(x)=\varphi_x$.

The claim is that $\operatorname{Baire}(X)=\{\varphi^{-1}(B):B\in \operatorname{Baire}([0,1]^{C(X,[0,1])}\}$.

Here $\operatorname{Baire}(X)$ is the smallest $\sigma$-field on $X$ such that any $f\in C(X)$ is measurable.

---

I've tried a few different approaches, but haven't got too far.

For ease of writing call $\{\varphi^{-1}(B):B\in \operatorname{Baire}([0,1]^{C(X,[0,1])}\}$ by $\mathcal{A}$. Let $\mathcal{B}=\operatorname{Baire}(X)$. Then $\mathcal{B}$ is generated by the zero sets of $X$ (this is given, and a zero set here is $Z_f=\{x\in X:f(x)=0\}$, $f\in C(X)$). Let $f\in C(X)$ want $Z_f\in \mathcal{A}$. Without loss of generality, $f\in C(X,[0,1])$, since by letting $f'=\min\{f,1\}$ $f'$ is continuous and $Z_{f'}=Z_f$.

Now, I want to show that $Z_f\in \mathcal{A}$, but I haven't been able to.

For the reverse inclusion, I haven't much more success. Is it true that a Baire measurable set is the zero set of a Baire measurable function?